# Cocos2d layer and touches priority management

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have my main scene, above it i set a new layer with `CCLayer` ,this layer has a button.
but when i hit that button (`CCMenu`), the layer behind it is also get the touches and do stuff.

I want to enable ONLY the upper layer touches, not the one under it .
How can i do that ? (setting touch priority ? how ? )

edit:

my layer is like that :

```
-(CCLayer*)showHelpLayer
{

    self.isTouchEnabled=YES;
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector].touchDispatcher addTargetedDelegate:self priority:-256 swallowsTouches:YES];
...
...

     [self addChild:menu];
    [menu setHandlerPriority:-257];
    return self;
}
```

and i am adding it to the main scene like that :

```
    helpLayer *hlp=[[helpLayer alloc]init];
    [hlp showHelpLayer];
    [self addChild:hlp z:100];
```

Answer (score 1):

you could toy with priorities, but it gets nasty. I only do that in very very specific, well contained circumstances. The best approach is to disable input on your "underneath scene(s)" before you push the new layer and control objects.

If you chose to play with priorities, remember that all menus default to this priority (cocos2D 2.xx) :

```
kCCMenuHandlerPriority = -128,
```

so if you play with priority, i would put the layer at -256 (swallowing touches) and setHandlerPriority to -257 for your menu. So anything that falls through your menu is caught by the layer and swallowed (ie not passed 'below').

example for priority approach. The fly-through menu is a class that extends CCNode and does this onEnter, after creating all menu objects in the init method :

```
- (void)onEnter {

    [super onEnter];

    MPLOGDEBUG(@"");
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector].touchDispatcher addTargetedDelegate:self priority:-256 swallowsTouches:YES];
    [_backMenu setHandlerPriority:-257];
    [_toggleOptionsMenu setHandlerPriority:-257];
    [_dialogMenu setHandlerPriority:-257];
    [_labelMenu setHandlerPriority:-257];
}
```

Comment: ok so i have set the layer that holds the menu to -256, with the touchDispatcher priority, then i have set the menu to be -257 with     [menu setHandlerPriority:-257]; , what happens is that the scene behind that layer does not get the touches of the layer, BUT also the menu in that layer dont get the touches ...

Comment: not certain if my explaination was clear, I added a working example from one of my 'push and pop' menu layers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. so if i understand you right, this code is on the upper pop layer class? this is exactly what i did ,and the menu is also dont get the touches...(the layer behind dont get the touches also)

Comment: I would not set isTouchEnabled since that registers the layer as a standard touch delegate. Comment out the line. Also, my example is from a class that extends CCNode (not CCLayer).

Comment: I took it out,still no luck for me .about the CCNode, i dont know what it means .

Comment: your menu objects must be created before onEnter is executed. onEnter is executed when you add the layer to the parent. So in effect, you must create the menu objects in an 'init' method. If you cant do that, immediately after you create your menu, set its handler priority.

Comment: so i remove everything to the init method, including the menu and the priority line, and still, the menu DONT get the touches . the layer behind is also doesnt.

Comment: I can also see that the layer DOES getting the touches , but the button on it does not. i have change its priority almost to any number in the world ..